# How do I return a hash object from a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, object, curl

I want to do something that I'm sure is simple but I can't gather how to do it from the documentation.

All I want to do is:

```
function something() {
 // Do some stuff with cURL
 set $object->name;
 set $object->corporation;
 // some if statement
 set $object->other; //if cURL finds "other" exists

 return $object;
}
```

And be able to do this:

```
$result = something();
$name = $result->name;
etc.
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I use procedural style and have very little know-how with objects hence I'm trying to learn.

Comment: What kind of object do you want there? Or you just don't care and want "a basic object"?

Comment: This look like basic OOP to me.

Comment: just create classes? :)

Comment: Read about [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in PHP.

Comment: Wanted to avoid putting classes in a function especially when the number of vars can fluctuate.

Comment: Using stdClass is rather besides the point of OOP though. In this case you could use a PHP array with keys "name", "other" as well and would reach the same goal. This doesn't make it OOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function foo(){
    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->name = "Joe";
    $result->other = "bar";
    return $result;
}
$object = foo();
echo $object->name; // Should display "Joe"
```